# Flaws with the following implementation of private state of instance objects

Tags: javascript, inheritance, design-patterns, private-members

I have read that private state of instance objects is generally not advised, and I would appreciate the help in pointing out the flaws/shortcomings of the following implementation.
Any advise/critique is greatly appreciated.

```
var namespace = {};

namespace.parent = {
    parent_method1 : function () {},
    parent_method2 : function () {}
};


namespace.child = function (properties) {

    var private="secret"; 

        this.prototype = {
        create : function () {
            this.unique = 'base';
            this.unique += this.properties;
                    return this.unique;
        },
            get_private: function () {
                console.log(private);
            },
            set_private: function (val) {
                private = val;
            }
        };


    var proto = Object.create(namespace.parent);
    var instance = Object.create(proto);
    for (var property in this.prototype) {
            if (this.prototype.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                proto[property] = this.prototype[property];
            }
    }   
        instance.properties = properties;
    return instance;  
};

var a = namespace.child("a");
console.log(a.create());
a.get_private();
a.set_private("new_a_secret");
a.get_private();

var b = namespace.child("b");
console.log(b.create());
b.get_private();
a.get_private();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would appreciate the help in pointing out the flaws/shortcomings of the following implementation.

I don't see anything wrong with your implementation of the `var private`, provided that it does what you expect it to do.

However, the big flaw of the code is: I don't understand it. What is your implementation supposed to do? It does not follow any of the standard patterns. This might be a shortcoming of the pseudo-methods and clear up when implementing a real world model; however as it stands it's quite confusing. Some documentation comments would help as well.

Specifically:

- What does `namespace.child` do? It looks like a factory function, but I'm not sure what "childs" it does produce.
- Also, for some reason it does set the `namespace.prototype` property to a new object on every invocation, which is then mixed into the <s>`instance` object</s> `proto` object. However, it leaves the internals (`get_private`, `set_private`) of the last created instance in global scope.
- Are `a` and `b` supposed to be classes? Why do they have `.create()` methods, that initialise the class (instance?) - and should rather be called `.init()` if at all? Why do they return the `.unique` property value?
- Why doesn't the `child` method initialize those factored objects right away?
- What is that `.properties` field that holds a string value?
- Why are you using two-level inheritance for those `instance` objects? `Object.create(namespace.parent)` is understandable, it inherits from a static object that is shared. But why is then `Object.create(proto)` used, copying some properties (`create`, `get_private`, `set_private`) on the `proto` and some properties (`properties`, `unique`) on the `instance`? Why distinguish between them?

Comment: Well, then it doesn't work, as neither `a` nor `b` are instantiable.

Comment: namespace.child is supposed to be a factory function that produces classes; init() is a better way of naming the initialization function .unique was used to (confusingly?) show that they return something unique based on .properties - storing a string is just an example. get_private, set_private and create(well init) are supposed to be shared between each class instance, (including the parent_method1 and parent_method2) is there a better way to make them all shared against the factored classes, perhaps under one level of inheritance as you suggested?

Comment: The problem is that `create` (or `init`) actually intialises *the class itself*, instead of creating an *instance of the class*. Your terminology "*shared between each class instance*" is ambigous, do you mean the class objects or the instance objects?

Comment: Thanks Bergi, I meant this.prototype methods to be shared between each child that come out of the factory. Will coping this.prototype methods to the instance object be sufficient as opposed to adding another inheritance level? Apologies for being confusing, I'm a newbie at this stuff.

Comment: No, they are not - every call to `.child()` creates a new `.prototype` object with its own methods. Only the properties of `namespace.parent` are shared between them. Notice that sharing them would mean that `a.set_private(…)` would affect `b.get_private()` (which it currently does not, as seen in your demo, so I thought this to be expected)